# Se puede considerar en un datawarehouse fechainicio y fechafin como dos dimensiones distintas

Tags: base-de-datos

Hola estoy haciendo un datawarehouse para analizar incidencias, tengo una dimensión fecha, y tengo mi tabla de hecho solicitud, pero la solicitud tiene una fecha de inicio y fecha fin, debo crear una dimensión fecha inicio y otra dimensión fecha fin? Es correcto eso en un datawarehouse, que sugerencias me pueden dar?

Saludos

Comment: la dimension fecha a que hace referencia? a un calendario? pero no se relaciona con las fechas de las solicitudes.. o si?

Comment: Si se relaciona con la tabla de hecho solicitudes

Comment: Estas pidiendo sugerencias. Y no se si hay una respuesta correcta a tu pregunta. Yo con tan poca informacion no la tengo. Pero si sirve para el modelo no estaria mal vrearla.